# buscar un texto dentro de un texto largo con RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Utilizando regextester genere un regex que me permite buscar un texto específico dentro de un texto largo sin espacios, ahora este me gustaría usarlo de forma dinamica para ir buscando diferentes palabras, intente pasarlo a dinamico pero no consigo que funcione.

intento hacer una búsqueda con este código

el regex original que si funciona [image: es este]

```
const rt = "8.469.505-k"
const ex = '\\b(\w*'+ rt +'\w*)\\b'

const cleanT = text.replace(/ /g, "")
if( cleanT.match(new RegExp(ex, 'g')) ){
  console.log("si encontro")
}
```

Comment: Hola Luis, por favor, en lugar de adjuntar la regex como un pantallazo, agrégala como texto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```js
const text = 'aaaaa8.469.505-kaaaaa';

const rt = "8.469.505-k";

const ex = '\\b(\\w*'+ rt +'\\w*)\\b';

const cleanT = text.replace(/ /g, "");

if( cleanT.match(new RegExp(ex, 'g')) ){
  console.log("si encontro")
}
```

No veo mucho problema a tu código, salvo un par de líneas que no terminan en punto y coma y la regex en formato string, que le faltaba alguna contrabarra (en `\\w`)

Ten en cuenta que si intentas reciclar la variable `rt` y `ex` para crear expresiones regulares nuevas dinámicamente, entonces no deberías definirlas como `const`, ya que no se permitirá su modificación.